# Existence of certain cofibrant replacement functors

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

Suppose we have a model category whose factorisations are not required to be functorial (as defined by Dwyer and Spalinski, for instance). In this case, when we choose (still non-functorial) cofibrant replacements $QX$'s of objects $X$'s of the category, we can clearly choose $QX=X$ if $X$ is already cofibrant.

On the other hand, it is well know that if we have a model category with functorial factorisations (as defined by Hovey, for instance), there is a cofibrant replacement functor $Q$ defined in terms of those functorial factorisations which in general does not operate as the identity on the subcategory of cofibrant objects.

Now my question is: suppose we have a model category with functorial factorisations. Can we change those factorisations (obtaining a new model structure over the same category with the same classes of weak equivalences, fibrations and cofibrations) in such a way that the resulting cofibrant replacement functor on this new model category acts as the identity on the category of cofibrant objects?

Comment: There are some degenerate cases where it is easy, but I am unaware of any candidate procedure that works in general. I also don’t know any impossibility results but it would be very surprising if it could always be done.